# I have an array of variables, can I attach a word to each variable element so they turn into another existing set of variables?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of variables:

```
let fruits = [apple, orange, banana];
```

These variables target specific DOM elements

```
apple = document.getElementById("apple");
orange = document.getElementById("orange");
banana =  document.getElementById("banana");
```

I also happen to have another set of variables that basically have "Rot" added to them

```
appleRot = document.getElementById("appleRot");
orangeRot = document.getElementById("appleRot");
bananaRot = document.getElementById("appleRot");
```

Is it possible to loop through the existing array and add "Rot" to each element so they target the other set of existing variables?

```
let fruits = [apple, orange, banana];
let fruitsRot = fruits.map((x) => x + "Rot");
```

is something like this possible without the result being a string but an array of elements that happen to target the second set of variables?

Comment: Include the HTML because the nature of your intent is nebulous. Adding "Rot" which isn't a string doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It really depends on how you're using these elements. How are the `rot` fruits different from the normal fruits? What does the code do them? Since you already have the elements on the page the array seems slightly redundant. Would adding a `fruit` class to each element and using `document.querySelectorAll('.fruit')` be easier to use, for example?

Comment: I'd use the names in the array instead: `const fruitNames = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']; const fruits = fruitNames.map(fruitName => document.getElementById(fruitName)); const rottenFruits = fruitNames.map(fruitName => document.getElementById(\`${fruitName}Rot\`));`

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. Use:

```
const fruits = [
   document.getElementById("apple"),
   document.getElementById("orange"),
   document.getElementById("banana"),];
const fruitsRot = fruits.map((x) =>
  document.getElementById(x.id + "Rot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a new element based on a known element's id, try this:

```
let fruits = [apple, orange, banana];
let fruitsRot = fruits.map((x) => {
    const {id} = x;
    const newId = id + "Rot";
    return document.getElementById(newId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a classic way:

```js
let fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
let fruitsRot = [];

for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    fruitsRot.push(fruits[i] + "Rot");
}

console.log(fruitsRot)
```

To loop through an existing array and add "Rot" to each element, you can use a for loop and the `push()` method. The for loop allows you to iterate over the elements of the array, and the `push()` method allows you to add a new element to the end of the array.

Finally you can use your `document.getElementById(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the names in the array instead:

```js
const fruitNames = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
const fruits = fruitNames.map(fruitName => document.getElementById(fruitName));
const rottenFruits = fruitNames.map(fruitName => document.getElementById(`${fruitName}Rot`));
```